# Error when passing template parameters to inner structure

Tags: c++, templates

I try to compile the following C++ code:

```
struct A {
    template< bool x >
    bool fun() {
        return x;
    }
};

template< typename T >
struct B {
    struct A2 {
        template< bool x >
        bool fun() {
            return x;
        }
    };

    void test() {
        A a;
        A2 a2;
        a.fun< true >();
        a2.fun< true >();
    }
};
```

The compiler complains that:

```
source_file.cpp: In member function ‘void B<T>::test()’:
source_file.cpp:22:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
         a2.fun< true >();
                        ^
```

However the line just above (`a.fun< true >()`) compiles just fine. Interestingly, if I remove the line `template< typename T >`, then compilation succeeds. However that line is required for reasons that do not appear from the minimal (not) working example. What is wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: @TristanBrindle I'm not sure of how these cases are handled, but the question is not a duplicate: maybe, in a sense, the answers convey the same information, but the questions are different; OP in the question you link already knows what the "template" keyword is and asks precisations on it; I did not know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context `A2` is actually a shorthand for `B<T>::A2`. Since `A2` is a type dependent on the template parameter `T`, you have to refer to its member templates with an explicit `template` keyword

```
a2.template fun< true >();
```

`A` is not a dependent type and its member templates can be referred to with "plain" syntax without that extra `template` keyword.

See 14.2/4 and a similar example there

> **14.2 Names of template specializations [temp.names]**
>
> **4** When the name of a member template specialization appears after `.` or `->` in a *postfix-expression* or after a *nested-name-specifier* in a *qualified-id*, and the object expression of the *postfix-expression* is type-dependent or the *nested-name-specifier* in the *qualified-id* refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword `template`.
>   Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct X { 
>    template<std::size_t> X* alloc();
>    template<std::size_t> static X* adjust();
>  };
>  template<class T> void f(T* p) {
>    T* p1 = p->alloc<200>();          // ill-formed: < means less than
>    T* p2 = p->template alloc<200>(); // OK: < starts template argument list
>    T::adjust<100>();                 // ill-formed: < means less than
>    T::template adjust<100>();        // OK: < starts template argument list
>  }
> ```
>
> —end example ]